# Folium Choropleth maps in FeatureGroup / Layers: missing scale?

Tags: python, folium, choropleth

I can get Folium to produce choropleth maps individually; they always include the scale and legend.

I've also figured out how to get them grouped into FeatureGroups, so I can display different layers on one map (see code below).

But when I do so, the scale / legend disappears. This makes the maps much less intelligible! Is there a way to fix this and restore the scale/legend?

```py
m = folium.Map(location=[40, -96],tiles = None)

for group in groups:
  layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name = group, overlay = False).add_to(m)
  
  cp = folium.Choropleth(
          geo_data = counties,
          data = map_df, 
          columns = ['FIPS','ScaleTotPop'],
          key_on = 'feature.properties.FIPS',
          bins = 9,
          fill_color='OrRd',
          fill_opacity=0.8,
          line_opacity=0.2,
          nan_fill_color = 'grey',
          legend_name='Percent of county population'
          ).geojson.add_to(layer) # <- WHY geojson here?

folium.TileLayer('OpenStreetMap',overlay=True,control = False).add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

I have two related questions [1](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458035) and [2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/458040) about multiple choropleth maps in Folium.

Thanks for any suggestions!
Adam

Comment: You have `overlay` set to `False` for `FeatureGroup`. Also, you're adding `layer` to `m`, then `cp` to `layer`... I feel like `layer` should be added to `m` after adding `cp` to it, not before.

Comment: Thanks! the `overlay=False` controls whether I want the layer to be an overlay (tick box; can have multiple layers displayed) or a base layer (with a radio button; only one layer displays at a time). I want the latter. <br> I agree with your feeling about when the layer should be added to m; interestingly, I've tried it both ways and it doesn't seem to matter. I think this is because with in the map "container", each layer is a separate unit/container. So I can put data into the container before or after it's put into the map container.

Comment: I've got the same issue. Could you manage to fix it?